# cannot set two-way bindings using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, binding

here is my father component

```
(function (app) {
    app.component('voiceFormComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/voice-form.html',
        controller: ['$state', '$stateParams', '$http', 'updateService', 'uploadService', 'countriesService', 'flagsService',
            function ($state, $stateParams, $http, updateService, uploadService, countriesService, flagsService) {

                var self = this;
                console.log("in voice prompt component");

                self.filesToUpload = [];


                self.submit = function () {
                    if (self.filesToUpload.length > 0) {
                            self.uploadFiles();
                    }
                ...
```

and its html:

```
                            <!--upload files-->
                            <upload-files-component voice-id="$ctrl.voice.id" files-to-upload="$ctrl.filesToUpload" has-files="$ctrl.hasFiles"></upload-files-component>
                        </div>
```

it has a 2 way binding with a component in it

```
(function (app) {
    app.component('uploadFilesComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/upload-files-partial.html',

        bindings: {filesToUpload: '='},
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            var self = this;

            $scope.$watch('files.length', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log($scope.files);
                this.filesToUpload = $scope.files;
            });
        }]
    })
})(promptoWeb);
```

how come the `self.filesToUpload` is filled in the son-component

but `self.filesToUpload.length === 0` in the father component

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to avoid these problems just modify object in child, do not create new. For array, just set length to 0 and add new elements.

1. What is '='? You tell that this is same object, so you have `chil.property` and `parent.property` pointing same object.
2. Now you say `chil.property = anotherObject`. Angular is still usuall javascript, so this can not modify `parent.property`. Now these two points different objects.
3. Now when `$digest` will run - this will be fixed and they will point new object. Demonstration:

> ```
> app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
>   $scope.twoway = 'initial';
>
>   $scope.callback = function(param) {
>     console.log('child value: ' + param);
>     console.log('parent value: ' + $scope.twoway);
>     $timeout(function() {
>        console.log('parent value after digest: ' + $scope.twoway);
>     });
>   }
> });
>
> app.component('test', {
>         template: '<div></div>',
>
>         bindings: {twoway: '=', callback: '&'},
>         controller: ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
>
>             var self = this;
>
>             $timeout(function() {
>               self.twoway = 'new';
>               self.callback({param: self.twoway});
>             })
>         }]
>     })
> ```

Output:

```
child value: new
parent value: initial
parent value after digest: new
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5K7CtsL0Bnp3RfuM30ac?p=preview